I am getting exception while fetching data... The method '[]' was called on null
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building ProfileScreen(dirty, state: \_ProfileScreenState#189a3):
The method '\[\]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: \[\]("firstname")

Code:
class EditProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditProfile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditProfileState createState() => _EditProfileState();
}

class _EditProfileState extends State<EditProfile> {
  bool isApiCallProcess = false;
  bool hidePassword = true;
  var _loadedProducts;
  late SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;
  static final GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _firstnameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _lastnameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _mobileController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _addressController = TextEditingController();

  final validator1 = ValidationBuilder().email().maxLength(50).build();

  String? firtname;
  String? lastname;
  String? email;
  String? mobile;
  String? address;



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchData();
  }


  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    var _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //store var userid = _shrePr.getInt('userid');
    var userid = _sharedPreferences.getInt('userid');
    if (userid != null) {
      userid = userid;
    } else {
      userid = 1;
    }

    print(userid.toString() + 'hello');

    final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('${Utils.baseUrl}/profile/getData'),
        headers: {"Accept": "Application/json"},
        body: {'user_id': userid.toString()});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var decodedData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(decodedData);
    }
    else{
      throw Exception('Failed to load..');
    }

    var f_data = json.decode(response.body);

    print(f_data);
    setState(() {
      _loadedProducts = f_data["data"][0];
    });
  }


Please add the build method implementations as well

make sure your f_data has your required data fieal is comming.
PS: And also make this code with using try catch bloc
and also make sure this assigned to data object and then get data from model.

There is a typo firtname (missing "s") in the code above.

@Kasun Hasanga Thank you for you time. The error was due to time taken for data fetch from the API.

@Markus  Thank you for you time. The error was due to time taken for data fetch from the API.

@dev  Thank you for you time. The error was due to time taken for data fetch from the API.

I guess you attached the wrong screen code to your question. Anyways I recommend to search for ["firstname"] in your ProfileScreen and try to handle case when object you calling ["firstname"] on is null

Thank you. The error is due to late data fetch from api.
